# Failure to update model from database using EF 5 and VS 2015

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have a C# application using Oracle database and Entity Framework 5. Oracle client is version 12c R1. My application uses database first approach. I'm trying to run the app using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. When I access the edmx file and I try to update the model from the database, it gives me the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: 'Unable to convert runtime connection string to its design-time equivalent. The libraries required to enable Visual Studio to communicate with the database for design purposes (DDEX provider) are not installed for provider 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Connection string: XXXXX.

This error does not occur when I use Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Only on Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

Is there any known incompatibility issue with the new one?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue for SQLite in VS2017. I believe this is probably because my machine doesn't have System.Data.SQLite components installed (they're not available yet as of this writing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is because not yet out ODT version compatible with Visual Studio 2015. Wait or will have no choice for now?

[Oracle Developer Tools](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html)

Comment: It makes sense. I believe I'll have to keep switching between 2013 and 2015 then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For while now I've done it. Change with the 2013 and 2015 until leaving the upgrade to 2015 to see if it will solve.

Comment: Looks like Oracle released a VS2015 ODT on October 29, 2015.  I installed that using the link from @FernandoArce, and that fixed my error. Everything works great for me now.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the Oracle Developer Tools for 2015 but still could not get this to work.  When I would attempt to do an Update Model from Database with Entity Framework, I encountered this error below.

[image]

So I did as instructed and removed all references to Oracle from the GAC, even following advice here [Oracle .Net Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT152), but it still didn't work.  Being that I'm on a tight schedule and don't have time to fool with this, I opened my solution in VS2012, did my Entity Framework changes, and then reopened the solution in VS2015, and that worked fine.  Irritating, but at least I have a workaround for now.